# How to serialize objects using pickle in python3

Tags: python-3.x, object, serialization

I read "How to think like a Computer Scientist. Learning with Python." book. So I usually have no difficulties to interpret examples from python2 to python3, but at chapter 11 Files & Exceptions I encountered this snippet

```
>>> import pickle
>>> f = open("test.pck", "w")
>>> pickle.dump(12.3, f)
>>> pickle.dump([1,2,3], f)
>>> f.close()
```

which when I evaluate it using Python 3.5.2 gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/(myDirs)/files.py", line 3, in <module>
    pickle.dump(3.14, f)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I am not a good docs reader, so if you can help me to solve this riddle I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode.

In line 2:

```
f = open("test.pck", "wb")
```